# with break statement in redux doesn't get me actual output in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, switch-statement

I have some issues with my reactJS code. I want to use a switch case with a break statement in redux but it doesn't get me the expected output and not getting any kind of error.

I have one file named

> **Reducer.js**

```
export default function CardItems(state=[],action){
switch(action.type){
    case ADD_TO_CART:
        console.warn('reducer case Add', action)
        return [
            ...state,
            { cardData: action.data },
        ]
        break;
    case REMOVE_TO_CART:
        console.warn('reducer case Remove', action)
        state.pop();
        return [
            ...state,
        ]          
        break;
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

when I am commenting break statement it works perfectly. why? I cant understand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `break` because you're exiting a function with `return` so `break` is unreachable.